# Synchronize vim settings across mac and Ubuntu server when using NeoBundle

Tags: linux, macos, git, vim

I want to synchronize the vim settings across my Mac and remote linux Ubuntu server. I am using `NeoBundle` for package management. I did the following:

1. On the Mac I installed NeoBundle and created a vimrc file in `~/.vim/`. See below for the .vimrc file.
2. On the Mac I symlinked to this vimrc file using `ln -s ~/.vim/vimrc ~/.vimrc`
3. I entered .vim directory and made it into a git repository adding everything to the repository except .netrwhist and *.swp
4. Then I pushed this repository to bitbucket.
5. I logged into the server. Deleted .vim and .vimrc. Created a symlink `ln -s ~/.vim/vimrc ~/.vimrc`.
6. Then I created .vim on the server and ran git clone of the pushed repository. I see all the files on the server that I see on my mac.

The bundles are all in `.vim/bundles`. So they are available.

The Vim versions are different. Is that the problem?

On Mac it says:

> VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Dec 19 2013 15:19:49)

whereas on the server it says:

> VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan 2 2014 19:39:32)

**Problem:** Vim works great on the Mac. But on the server when I run vim I get the following error:

```
Error detected while processing /home/admin/.vimrc:
line   16:
E117: Unknown function: neobundle#begin
line   20:
E492: Not an editor command:  NeoBundleFetch 'Shougo/neobundle.vim'
line   26:
E117: Unknown function: neobundle#end
line   33:
E492: Not an editor command:  NeoBundleCheck
line   38:
E492: Not an editor command: NeoBundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
line   39:
E492: Not an editor command: NeoBundle 'terryma/vim-multiple-cursors'
line   40:
E492: Not an editor command: NeoBundle 'tomasr/molokai'
line   41:
E492: Not an editor command: NeoBundle '29decibel/codeschool-vim-theme'
line   42:
E492: Not an editor command: NeoBundle 'Lokaltog/vim-easymotion'
line   43:
E492: Not an editor command: NeoBundle 'jnurmine/Zenburn'
line   64:
E185: Cannot find color scheme 'zenburn'
```

The .vimrc contains:

```
"================================================================================
"   NeoBundle settings (copied from NeoBundle github page)
"================================================================================
 " Note: Skip initialization for vim-tiny or vim-small.
 if !1 | finish | endif

 if has('vim_starting')
   set nocompatible               " Be iMproved

   " Required:
   set runtimepath+=~/.vim/bundle/neobundle.vim/
 endif

 " Required:
 call neobundle#begin(expand('~/.vim/bundle/'))

 " Let NeoBundle manage NeoBundle
 " Required:
 NeoBundleFetch 'Shougo/neobundle.vim'

 " My Bundles here:
 " Refer to |:NeoBundle-examples|.
 " Note: You don't set neobundle setting in .gvimrc!

 call neobundle#end()

 " Required:
 filetype plugin indent on

 " If there are uninstalled bundles found on startup,
 " this will conveniently prompt you to install them.
 NeoBundleCheck
"================================================================================


" Install these packages
NeoBundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
NeoBundle 'terryma/vim-multiple-cursors'
NeoBundle 'tomasr/molokai'
NeoBundle '29decibel/codeschool-vim-theme'
NeoBundle 'Lokaltog/vim-easymotion'
NeoBundle 'jnurmine/Zenburn'


"================================================================================
"      Editor view settings
"================================================================================      
syntax on
set number 

" size of a hard tabstop
set tabstop=4
" size of an indent
set shiftwidth=4
" always use spaces instead of tab characters
set expandtab

set guifont=Monaco:h16

if has("gui_running")
    colorscheme codeschool
else
    colorscheme zenburn
endif


"=================================================================================
"       Other settings
"=================================================================================
" Use Ctrl-s to save a file in insert mode. 
inoremap <C-s> <C-c>:w<ENTER>

" make working directory same as the file being edited
" may interfere with some plugins (see here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Set_working_directory_to_the_current_file)
set autochdir
```

Comment: What version of Vim is on the server?  Is the bundles you are referring to in your `.vimrc` available on the server?

Comment: The bundles are all in .vim/bundles. So they are available. The Vim versions are different. Is that the problem? On Mac it says: `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Dec 19 2013 15:19:49)`, whereas on the server it says, `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan  2 2014 19:39:32)`

Comment: @vgoff Actually, you are right. The folders of the bundles are there on the server. However, they are empty. This is weird. Why is git not including the contents of these in the repository?

Comment: I haven't looked at it, but it may be a submodule?

Comment: I think the bundles have their own git inside them. Perhaps. for that reason my git repository ignores them.

Comment: They would be submodules then.  See `man git-submodule` for details.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this post is aging, as there is still no answers, I figured I might give my take on this issue. As I'm synchronizing my configuration directories across computers mixing OSX and Linux, I thought I'd share the way I've done it, for future reference, if you did solve your question.

First of all, I split my vim configuration in two directories:

- `~/.vim/` that contains the [`vimrc`](https://github.com/guyzmo/vimrc/blob/master/vimrc) configuration file and neobundle, meant to be shared across all computers
- `~/.local/vim` that contains the bundles, swap files and undo files.

Here's a tree of the first `~/.vim/`:

```
$HOME/.vim
 ├── README.md
 ├── neobundle.vim
 │   ├── LICENSE-MIT.txt
 │   ├── Makefile
 │   └── […] (all neobundle contents)
 └── vimrc
```

First let's set up undofiles in the [`~/.vim/vimrc`](https://github.com/guyzmo/vimrc/blob/master/vimrc) file:

```
" undo file
set undofile
set undodir=~/.local/vim/undofiles
set undolevels=2000
set history=200
```

and swapfiles:

```
" swap files
set directory=~/.local/vim/swapfiles
```

so that they're not synchronized between computers and mess up with each others. No, you don't want the undo of computer A on computer B, and even worst, you don't want all your standard unix `/home/foo/*` mixed with the non-standard `/Users/foo/*`…

Then, in my [`~/.vim/vimrc`](https://github.com/guyzmo/vimrc/blob/master/vimrc), I setup neobundle the following way:

```
" NeoBundle setup {{{
filetype off
set runtimepath+=~/.vim/neobundle.vim/
call neobundle#begin(expand('~/.local/vim/bundle'))
NeoBundleFetch 'Shougo/neobundle.vim'
" }}}
```

that's where the trick is: you set up the runtimepath to add the `neobundle.vim` addon bundle "manually" to the runtimepath of vim within `~/.vim`, then you start neobundle by telling him where to find/install bundles. Following that in the `vimrc` file, you setup all your favorite bundles, and finally you end it with:

```
" NeoBundle Prologue {{{
call neobundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on " required!
NeoBundleCheck
" }}}
```

So, now, when I'm deploying vim on a new computer, all I have to do, is:

```
git clone https://github.com/guyzmo/vimrc ~/.vimrc
mkdir -p ~/.local/vim/bundle
mkdir ~/.local/vim/undofiles
mkdir ~/.local/vim/swapfiles
vim +NeoBundleInstall +qall
```

Finally, if that solution answers your question is that you keep in sync *only* the necessary static stuff (what plugins and what configuration), and generate all the dynamic stuff locally to each computer. So, you leave Neobundle do its job, cloning git repositories, compiling and installing files. For example, look at youcompleteme setup, where it is defined how to install it depending on the host you're running your vim on. And also, you'll never have any more git issues.

HTH